# Send the results of an API POST request in one component to another component for use?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I have followed the tutorial **[HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#make-post-put-and-delete-requests)** for making a POST request to an API, and it works well; I have successfully requested -> received -> and processed the data.

I am now trying to expand what I have learned and use it in my larger application, but I don't know what do do.

I am using the `Index.razor` page as my "root" page. In this root page, I have some logic to decide what to display on the page. If there are no results to process, I display the search input form (`DefaultSearch.razor`). If there are results to process, I display those results (`SearchResultsPage.razor`).

My issue is that I do not know how to **(1)** Send the inputted query string from `DefaultSearch.razor` component back to the root page for processing, and **(2)** how to send those returned, processed results to the `SearchResultsPage.razor` component for display.

**Index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
<div class="text-center">
    <HeaderLarge />
        @if (fetchedResults == null)
        {
            <DefaultSearch />
        } else {
            <SearchResultsPage />
        }
</div>

@code {
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.234:8080");
        Search search = new Search(queryString);
        string searchstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(search);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(searchstr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(("/api/...", content);
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResultSet>(response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**DefaultSearch.razor:**

```
<div id="SearchContainer">
    <div id="SearchFormContainer">
        <input id="mainSearchInputField" name="queryString" type="text" /><button @onclick()>Search</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

**SearchResultsPage.razor:**

```
@page "/search"
<h3>SearchResultsPage</h3>
<div>
    @if (fetchedResults != null)
    {
        @foreach (var result in fetchedResults.documents)
        {
            <div>
                <table class="message">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Subject</td>
                        <td>@(result.subject)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>@result.docId</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="message_body" colspan="2">
                            <span>@(result.messageBody)</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public SearchResultSet fetchedResults { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `Index.razor` just an example of what you want? That's not a valid razor component `@code` block.

Comment: @ConnorLow Well, it is, but it should be valid. I copied my code from my working test program. If it is all not there, then I must have forgotten something. I am successfully getting data back from the API, so that is not what I need assistance with. But, generally, this is what I want.

Comment: You're using .NET 5? You can't put a `try` directly into a `@code` block: it should be wrapped in a method. Essentially, you are placing that code in a class definition, but it should be in a method definition.

Comment: @ConnorLow Thank you, but that is not what I am asking for. I need to find out how to get submitted data from`DefaultSearch.razor` to `Index.razor` and the results from `Index.razor` to `SearchResultsPage.razor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values up to a parent components using `EventCallback`s, and down to children using `[Parameter]`s. Here is a generalized solution with your component names:

**DefaultSearch.razor** (child A)

```cs
<input @bind-value="SearchValue" />
<button @onclick="Handle">Search</button>

@code{
    string SearchValue { get; set; }

    // Allows parent to listen for the 'click' event on the search button
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnClick { get; set; }

    async Task Handle()
    {
        if(OnClick.HasDelegate)
        {
            // Calls the EventCallback, passing the search term
            await OnClick.InvokeAsync(SearchValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.razor** (parent):

```cs
<DefaultSearch OnClick="HandleSearch" />
<SearchResultsPage FetchedResults="Results" />

@code {
    SearchResultSet Results { get; set; }

    async Task HandleSearch(string searchTerm) {
        // However you need to get your results here:
        Results = await GetResultsForSearchTerm(searchTerm);

        // Signal a re-render from an async opperation.
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**SearchResultsPage.cs** (child B):

```cs
<!-- markup here -->

@code {
    // Receive the result set here:
    [Parameter]
    public SearchResultSet FetchedResults { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm ... clicking the button in `DefaultSearch.razor` doesn't seem to be triggering anything.

Comment: Depends on what you told it to do. Note, as I said in the post, this is a generalized solution. You need to provide your own logic to fill in the gaps; verity that it's not "triggering anything" by running in Debug with VS or VS Code, or use `System.Console.WriteLine` to verify execution.